# Find $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$ with infinite order, that have finite order in the addition (coordinate by coordinate)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I need to find elements $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$ with infinite order such that $a + b$ has finite order (addition of coordinates).

I'm starting studying group theory and I'm a bit confused with this problem. What I did was:

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{ \overline{0}, \overline{1} \}$ and $\mathbb{Z} = \{ \overline{0} \}$

So the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$ are $\{ (\overline{0}, \overline{0}), (\overline{1}, \overline{0}) \}$

And both elements have finite order... $o((\overline{0}, \overline{0})) = 1$ and $o((\overline{1}, \overline{0})) = 2$

Seems I have some wrong ideas here. Anyone can guide me a bit on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have your definition of $\Bbb Z$ wrong. It's simply the set of all integers; what you are thinking of is probably $\Bbb Z_1$ which is the trivial group with one element.

So $a = (0, 1)$ and $b = (0, -1)$ would be a solution; they both have infinite order (because 1 and -1 have infinite order in $\Bbb Z$), and $a + b$ is the identity element.

Comment: You are right, I was mistaking $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}_1$... That's why I found it nonsense. Thanks!